# Spring ResponseEntityExceptionHandler doesn't work on https.bad_request

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm currently trying to handle my exceptions. If I return a `HttpStatus.CONFLICT I am able to get the responseBody in my javascript callback.
But, If I change for a`HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST`then I get an XML error`HTLM ERROR` :

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">*{margin:0px;padding:0px;background:#fff;}</style><title>HTTP ERROR</title><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://static.worlderror.org/http/error.js"></script></head><body><iframe src="http://www.worlderror.org/http/?code=400&lang=en_en&pv=2&pname=YVL4X9S]&pver=LArsJ6Sn&ref=ZqHaWUscWmgmYjz]&uid=wdcxwd5000aakx-753ca1_wd-wmayu624013840138" width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0"></iframe></body></html>
```

Can someone explain to me why ? And how to solve this using @ControllerAdvice.

**My @ControllerAdvice** (If I only change CONFLICT to BAD_REQUEST it doesn't work) :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    /** The associated logger. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpRestException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request)
    {
        final HttpRestException restEx = (HttpRestException) ex;
        LOGGER.info("Handling REST error {} : {}", restEx.getHttpStatus(), restEx.getErrorMessage());

        final String bodyOfResponse = "GET THIS ERROR";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse,
                new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

**How I throw my exception :**

```
throw new HttpRestException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                    "Unsupported encoding : " + e.getMessage());
```

I have to admit that I start to be completly mad about this exception handling thing with Spring... How can't this work only by changing the status.. I already looked into the super implementation and of course didn't found anything.
I also tried other way to do this without success, this one is the simplest so I want to stay with it.

Thank for your help !

**EDIT :**
Is this possible that tomcat intercept the 400 response and replace it with it's own content ?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the chances are the container is returning the error even before it hits any of your code. You can add an Error Handler for code 400 in your web.xml and have Tomcat forward to a Servlet, Controller, JSP or whatever you like.

See here for an example:

http://www.journaldev.com/1973/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial